# Red5 live streaming example using java

Tags: java, video-streaming, live-streaming, red5

I wanted to know is there any good documentation or example blog that shows how to use `Red5` with Java. Is it possible to to live streaming from remote camera using `Red5' ? . Any links or documentations are helpful.

Live streaming use case is, Record video from camera and send to Red5 server. Red5 server can restream the feed live to web or save it in the network storage. For this usecase `Red5` is good option ?

Thanks

Comment: you want to make in `Android` or `Ios`?

Comment: Currently only web based GUI is enough

Comment: because i have already done in 'Android', app work successfully